# usage of paintComponent and JPanel in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
//import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GuiDemo1 extends JPanel{


    public static void main(String[] args){
            JPanel panel=new JPanel();
            JFrame frame=new JFrame();
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(500, 400);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }



    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(20, 50, 100, 100);
        }

}
```

I am newbie to JAVA.I have written this sample program.However this is not working.Can some one point out the mistakes I have done.

And generally what is the use of calling super.paintComponent(g)?

Comment: You may want to be more specific about what is not working and what you have tried to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom painting was added to the GuiDemo1 class not the JPanel class:

```
//JPanel panel=new JPanel();
JPanel panel=new GuiDemo1();
```

> and generally what is the use of calling super.paintComponent(g)?>

You want that at the start of the paintComponent(...) method because it will do the default painting for the component, which in the case of a JPanel is basically just to paint the background. Try adding:

```
panel.setBackground( Color.BLUE );
```

and see what happens with/without the super.paintComponent(g).